# Cover $\mathbb{R}^3$ with skew lines

Tags: combinatorics

> Is there a covering of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with pairwise skew lines?

Comment: This is probably ignorant, but my gut reaction would be to define the (uncountable) set: $\{\ell_{x_0y_0}=(x_0,y_0,z), z\in\mathbb R:x_0,y_0\in\mathbb R\}$. Just take the line parallel to the $z$-axis at every point in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern skew lines *not* parallel lines, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92919/filling-mathbbr3-with-skew-lines

Comment: Ah! thank you @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. I'm going to delete this question.

Comment: Well, don't. The question I linked to does not directly answer your question; but the method given in its answer does apply to it, I think. If you manage to adapt it to your question, then add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $\omega = x_0 +  y_0 i\in \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Consider the set $l_{\omega} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by:

$$l_{\omega} = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} : \frac{x + iy}{1 + iz} = \omega \right\}$$

Since the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{x+iy}{1+iz}$ is defined over all $\mathbb{R}^3$, we have:

$$\mathbb{R}^3 = \cup_{\omega \in \mathbb{C}}\;l_{\omega}\quad\text{ and }\quad
l_{\omega_1} \cap l_{\omega_2} = \emptyset \;\text{ for distinct }\;\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \mathbb{C}$$

Furthermore, each $l_{\omega}$ is a straight line as it admits a linear parametrization:
   $$\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto ( x_0 - y_0 t,\, y_0 + x_0 t,\, t ) \in l_{\omega}$$
With this parametrization, one can see that its tangent vector is along the direction
proportional to $(-y_0, x_0, 1)$.
This means $l_{\omega_1} \not\parallel l_{\omega_2}$ for distinct $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

In short, $\{ l_{\omega} : \omega \in \mathbb{C} \}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into a family of lines in which all pairs are skew.

Answer (score 1):

Take some injection $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. interleaving of binary expansions). Now orient a line through each point $(x,y,z)$ with direction $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$ where $\theta=\tan^{-1}\varphi(x,y,z)$.

This gives a *covering* of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The answer to [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28647) can easily be modified to give a *partition*.