# How to prove that union of skew lines can be $\mathbb{R}^3$ using vector calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does one prove that union of skew lines can be $\mathbb{R}^3$ using vector calculus? Space-filling curve methods are available, but i would like to know the method using vector calculus, as I heard that the method exists.

Comment: Could you be more specific? $\mathbb R^3$ is, clearly, the union of all lines.

Comment: I just want to show that $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be a union of some skew lines. Isn't this all that can be provided?

Comment: That's clearly true. For each $x\in\mathbb R^3$ pick a skew line $\ell_x$ containing $x$ then $\mathbb R^3=\bigcup\{\ell_x: x\in\mathbb R^3\}$

Comment: @azarel What guarantees the lines are pairwise skew? Such a set can be constructed using the axiom of choice but that's likely not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @user7530 I don't see any restriction imposed on the set of lines. That's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: An explicit construction has been given in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/371692/59379). It uses complex numbers to help labeling the lines.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to foliate $\mathbb{R}^3$ with (one-sheet) hyperboloids. Each hyperboloid is ruled with skew lines, and by construction rulings of different hyperboloids aren't parallel and don't intersect.

See here for discussion of this problem:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1194/how-to-partition-r3-into-pairwise-non-parallel-lines/3714#3714