# Euclidean space as a sum of non-intersecting and non-parrarel lines

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible to represent $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ as a union of countable non-intersecting and non-coplanar lines?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371302/cover-mathbbr3-with-skew-lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they have measure 0, thus so does their countable union. Whereas $\mathbb R^3$ has infinite measure.

Also by the baire category theorem a complete metric space cannot be written as the countable union of closed, nowhere-dense sets and lines are nowhere dense in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: How about if I don't put the restriction to the union to be countable?

Comment: Unsure. My intuition says no but no proof comes to mind. Perhaps it is possible.